# matplotlib: stop figure to automatically maximize when the specified size at creation is close to the size of the screen

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a matplotlib figure that has the same size in two different size screens I use for work. I'm trying to set the size to the largest figure I can show in the smaller screen. I specify the size on creation like this:

```
f = plt.figure("test", figsize=(16, 12), dpi=100)
```

However the figure window automatically maximizes when shown. If I query the size of the figure I get:

```
manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
f.get_size_inches()
array([19.2, 10.7])
```

If the size I ask is not close to the size of the screen, the figure size seem to change less, for example:

```
f = plt.figure("test", figsize=(15, 12), dpi=100)
f.get_size_inches()
array([15.  , 10.68])
```

Thinking maybe it's a matter of having correct aspect ratios I tried:

```
f = plt.figure("test", figsize=(19.2, 10.7), dpi=100)
f.get_size_inches()
array([19.2, 10.7])


f = plt.figure("test2", figsize=(19.2*0.9, 10.7*0.9), dpi=100)
f.get_size_inches()
array([19.2, 10.7])!!!
```

How can I stop the window changing size/maximizing by itself?

Python 2.7.17
matplotlib '2.2.5'
Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: First note that your matplotlib version is extremely old. But the problem you encounter is probably out of matplotlib's control.

Comment: That's the latest matplotlib for python 2.7. And I'm stuck with python 2.7 because other requirements

Comment: Likely t's not Matplotlib, it's your window manager. I suggest asking on a site specific to your operating system.